# Sed/Awk: Delete all lines after last occurrence of pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with one insert on each line, like below:

```
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (1,x,b);
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (2,y,c);
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (3,w,d);
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (4,z,e);
-- Comment
SELECT * FROM table;
-- Comment
SELECT * FROM table;
```

How do I remove every line after the last ocurrence of INSERT INTO? Output I'm looking for is:

```
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (1,x,b);
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (2,y,c);
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (3,w,d);
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (4,z,e);
```

Comment: for given sample, you could just `grep 'INSERT INTO' file` ... if that doesn't help, please change sample to better represent your use case.. also, you are expected to show what you have tried.. otherwise it comes across as a free coding request

Comment: When I hear "do something *after the last* ..." I think of "reverse the file, and do something *before the first* ...". Have a close look at Kent's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gnu sed

If there is no comment before the last 'INSERT INTO'

```
sed -n '/INSERT INTO/{p;b};q' infile
```

If there are some comments before the last 'INSERT INTO'

```
sed -z 's/\(.*INSERT INTO[^\n]*\n\).*/\1/' infile
```

Answer (score 3):

The easier way is to use `tac`:

```
tac file|sed '0,/^INSERT INTO/{/INSERT INTO/!d}'|tac
```

You can also use awk without `tac`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if(/^INSERT INTO/)e=NR;next}FNR<=e' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an actual *file* rather than a stream, you can use an `ed` one-liner:

```
?^INSERT INTO?+,$d
```

This deletes (`d`) everything from the line after (`+`) the last that matches (`?...?`) the pattern `^INSERT INTO` up to the last line (`$`).

### Demo:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

filename=$(mktemp)

cat >>"$filename" <<'END'
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (1,x,b);
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (2,y,c);
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (3,w,d);
INSERT INTO table (columns) values (4,z,e);
-- Comment
SELECT * FROM table;
-- Comment
SELECT * FROM table;
END


ed -s "$filename" <<'END'
?^INSERT INTO?+,$d
wq
END


cat "$filename"
rm "$filename"
```